# How to filter by (child) domain class in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I have a parent domain class, Product:

```
class Product {
    ...
}
```

and more than 20 child classes extending it. One of this is ProductGroup:

```
class ProductGroup extends Product {
    ...
}
```

When creating an instance of ProductGroup, I have a multiselect input where products are listed and a user can select what products he/she wants to add to the group. Right now, I use Product.list() to populate the multiselect input. What I want to do is have a list of all products not including ProductGroup instances. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with HQL if not with native GORM:

```
Product.findAll("from Product p where p.class != ProductGroup")
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured I'd have to use HQL to do it.